# Order of nucleophilicity of ammonia, hydrazine and hydroxylamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, nucleophilicity

I was reading about nucleophilicity and basic strength orders. I came across this interesting set of three compounds $\ce{NH3},$ $\ce{N2H4}$ and $\ce{NH2OH}$ where I am not able to apply the rules I have learnt.

The correct order of basic strength is given to be:

> $K_\mathrm b$ value: $\ce{NH3} > \ce{N2H4} > \ce{NH2OH}$

The rules I know are:

1. If the donor atom is same, then order of nucleophilicity is same as the order of basicity.
2. Alpha effect: if the adjacent atom attached to the donating atom has lone pair of electrons, then nucleophilicity is enhanced.

When I try to conclude the nucleophilicity order, I am getting contradicting results with the above rules. Also, I wonder whether the −*I* effect due to the presence of highly electronegative atom may have a role to play.

So, what is the correct order of nucleophilicity of $\ce{NH3},$ $\ce{N2H4}$ and $\ce{NH2OH}?$

Is it theoretically possible to conclude the correct order based on deciding which factor will dominate in a given situation?

**CLARIFICATION**:

My doubt is pertaining to specifically these three compounds.Many have said that this question is a duplicate of [Is there a general consensus on the causes of the alpha-effect?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/is-there-a-general-consensus-on-the-causes-of-the-alpha-effect)
But, I am not able to get the order of nucleophilicity that I need from the answers to that question.I am not able to find the information on order of nucleophilicity of these three compounds in the books I use.So, it would be helpful if someone clarifies the position of $\ce{NH2OH}$ in this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a general consensus on the causes of the alpha-effect?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/is-there-a-general-consensus-on-the-causes-of-the-alpha-effect)

Comment: @Mithoron I have already seen that question.But, I am not able to get the answer to my question over there

Comment: Well, nucleophilicity has little to do with basicity, that's why alpha effect was coined.

Comment: But what would be the correct order then?I saw this somewhere:N2H4 >NH3>NH2OH first one eventhough Kb is less than ammonia due to lone pair-lone pair repulsion and larger size it becomes a better nucleophile and -I effect of oxygen dominate over alpha effect.Is this correct?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83072/is-hydrazine-a-better-nucleophile-than-ammonia

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this too.Still, the position of NH2OH isn't clear to me.Can you clarify that?

Comment: You can only come up with a rough trend. Nucleophilicity of substances differs in different contexts.

Comment: @Zhe Got your point.Still would like to know the rough trend.Thanks

Comment: @Chem-Learner Why do you keep on insisting on [tag:organic-chemistry] tag? There is not even a single carbon atom in any of the compounds you are asking about.

Comment: I was reading this in my organic chemistry course under the topic effect of Nucleophiles.So, I thought I may get a related answer if I include this tag in my question.